# CURL cli PUT request - send data and file

Tags: curl, command-line-interface, put

I'm working on PUT method of API which will update entity defined by ID in URL. I need to send file and some additional data for user authentication (like signature and user public key). I fount out how I can send file:

```
curl -v -X PUT -T "file.epub" localhost:8080/api/book/?id=123
```

And find out how I can send data

```
curl -v -X PUT --data test=abc localhost:8080/api/book/?id=123
```

But how can I send file and additional data fields?

Answer (score 3):

Just like:

```
curl -X PUT -F file=@file.epub -F test=abc localhost:8080/api/book/?id=123
```

I am assuming you can change your API, so you can upload the file using a parameter, and in this example the parameter is called `file`.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I don't understand very well what you mean by "you can upload the file using a parameter, and in this example the parameter is called file". I won't be able to initiate file uploading from user computer. Can you explain it in more details? Thanks.

Comment: Well, parameter `file` will be the raw content of the `file.epub`.

Comment: I tried this PUT request. When I process data came with request in PHP script I got strange values. First of all I receive 18 parameters while I pass only 2. The name of parameter for example: ------------------------------e2ece971afa8\r\nContent-Disposition:_form-data;_name. And there is no "test" parameter. At the same time with request curl -v -X PUT --data test=abc localhost:8080/api/book/?id=123 I can retrieve parameter with right name and right value. It seems that we send file in a wrong way for PUT request.

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -d "key1=value1" -d "key2=value2" -d @"/path/to/file" -X PUT your_url
```

PUT will not work with "-F" (e.g. curl -X PUT -F file=@file.epub -F test=abc localhost:8080/api/book/?id=123) as "-F" implies content type "multipart/form-data" header (-H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data") which does not work with PUT requests.